# Substitute reply-to, sendgrid smtp api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, sendgrid

Is it possible to substitute reply-to option in Sendgrid SMTP Api? If yes, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Each batch email has to share unique args and headers (except the subject header). So setting a unique reply-to address for each email is currently not possible.

The sub tags also only work for the body of an email and the subject.

But definitely request that as a feature on the sendgrid getsatisfaction page (http://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid). Its a great idea!